# How to retrieve a html text from rich text area into word document without html code by Bonita BPM?

Tags: html, decode, business-process-management, bonita, richtextarea

I am developing a Bonita application. 
I created a word document using by the connector.

### It works well. however, the data from a rich text area retrieve with HTML code.

For example,
This is the format of the word document.

```
    «${doc.firstName}» «${doc.lastName}»,

    «${today}»
    Request conclusion
    Dear «${doc.firstName}»,
    After review by the HR, your request for «${doc.requestCategory}» has been evaluated.

     Request conclusion:

        «${doc.conclusion}»
```

---

### And the result is as follow;

Walter Bates

2019-04-02

Request conclusion
Dear Walter,
After review by the HR, your request for Request has been evaluated.

Request conclusion:

< p >< b >Hello,< /b >< / p >< p >< b > This is conclusion < /b >< /p>

** In order to show the HTML code, I put some space between the code.

How to retrieve the HTML code from the BDM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm that my understanding is correct: you have a rich text area widget in a form (this widget output is HTML code that include content and formatting), when user submit the form the data are sent to the process trough the process or step contract, then the contract variable is used to set the process business variable value and then you are using this business variable value as input information for the Word document template connector. And your issue is that the generated Word document includes HTML instead of formatted text. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes. That is exactly what I am facing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent time looking at the connector source code and sadly I can confirm that the Word / ODT template connector currently does not support HTML formatting of a field. I have created a new entry for this improvement (for this Enterprise Edition feature) in our internal features/improvements tracker tool.

The only alternative I might suggest is to create your own connector.